# jQuery Accordion closed for mobile only

Tags: jquery, css

Since my site is responsive, is there a way (preferably using only CSS, since all the markup is already there,) to have my normally open accordion closed if it is viewed on a mobile device?

There's to much clutter for such a small screen size.

#### Filter Vehicles

Content

#### Useful Resources

Content 2

Comment: Accordions do usually require some form of JavaScript, but it's hard to suggest anything without seeing some markup. Show us some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for a CSS only solution, but without any code snippet to go off of, this it the best I can offer. Hopefully this will give you an idea of what needs to be done. Assuming you are using Bootstrap, you need to remove the .in class of any/all open panels. If you aren't using Bootstrap, than what ever is triggering the openness of the accorion needs to be targeted for closing.

Taken from here: [Accordions collapse by default in mobile and expanded by default in desktop Bootstrap 3 responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661442/accordions-collapse-by-default-in-mobile-and-expanded-by-default-in-desktop-boot)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if(windowWidth <= 1024) //for iPad & smaller devices
     $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in')
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked... I preferred pure CSS, but doesn't necessarily have to be...

Answer (score 0):

CSS Only:

```
@media (min-width: 704px) {
   .collapse {
      display: block !important;
      visibility: visible !important;
      height: 100% !important;
   }
}
```