# Widget DT-Accordion Wordpress if version mobile close if dekstop open

Tags: wordpress

i use DT-Accordion Widget wordpress

i want if mobile version accordion close

if desktop version the accordion open

how to build this sir?

this my code for the DT-Accordion sir :

```
    $html = sprintf(
        '<a class="text-primary" href="#"><span>%1$s</span></a><div class="st-content">%2$s</div>',
        $item['title'],
        wpautop( do_shortcode($item['content']) )
    );
```

i try like this on main.css :
this code not work sir

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .st-content {display:none;}
}
```

i try to add like this :

```
display:none!important;
```

this work, but the accordion not open on mobile version, but the accordion can not been click opened.

how to create the accordion not show on mobile version (close), and show on desktop version?

i try this :

[jQuery Accordion closed for mobile only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081014/jquery-accordion-closed-for-mobile-only)

not work

Please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

fixed/solved :
try this for hide/close the dt-accordion wordpress :

open main.min.css, and find .st-accordion>ul>li:first-child .st-content

and change the css like this :

```
@media (max-width: 728px) {
.st-accordion>ul>li:first-child .st-content
{display:none!important;}
}
.st-accordion>ul>li:first-child .st-content
{display:block;}
```